# Capitalization of adjectives with prefixes

Tags: adjective, orthography, prefix

When answering [a recent question about the prefix *per-*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/3029/79), I gave an example of a national adjective (*Finnus*) with a prefix, to produce *Perfinni*.
If I attach a prefix to an adjective that always starts with a capital letter, how do I capitalize?
It sounds most reasonable to capitalize the first letter of the prefix.
Other options that come to mind (*perfinni*, *perFinni*, *per-Finni*) look worse.
Is there a convention, and if yes, what is it?

Capitalization was not an ancient thing, but there might be some classical adjectives of this kind.
At least *Cisalpinus* and *Transrhenanus* come to mind.

Comment: How about *Per-Finnī*?

Comment: @Draconis That's a possibility. It does sound a little like "Finns called Per" (it's a first name), though...

Comment: Didn't you already answer your question with *Cisalpinus*?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Perhaps I did. If *Cisalpinus* is always spelled this way, that'd be a sufficient answer. I was just looking for confirmation.

Comment: I've never seen it otherwise.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Do you want to post that as an answer? It would be sufficient for me.

Comment: But MegaWatts and microNewtons encourage me to hope for perFinni. Together with subFahrenheit temperatures and nonEuclidian geometry.

Comment: @Hugh The conventions vary between different languages. // Mathematicians mostly write "non-Euclidean", sometimes "non Euclidean", but I don't recall ever seeing "nonEuclidean". But again, this is just the convention I have seen. // Aren't SI unit spelled lowercase in English: newton, watt, ...?

Comment: @Hugh In American English I've seen those with hyphens rather than camelcase: non-Euclidean, sub-Fahrenheit, non-Newtonian, hyper-Gaussian. (And I think they're supposed to be lowercase but I usually see those unit names capitalized.)

Comment: I think the version with the capital immediately after a lower-case letter is unacceptable in any language I know. The one with the hyphen looks decidedly Unlatin: it's English. I like Weimer's answer about the attached versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes down to editorial practice and whether it's being used as a proper name or not.

So in Caesar's *Gallic War*, Seel capitalized both Cisalpina and Gallia, because it's Cisalpina Gallia, one place (my edition by Du Pontet has the same):

> uos ex Cisalpina Gallia consulis sacramento rogasset

However, Rossbach left the C uncapitalized in his edition of the *Periochae* (same with the unknown TLL text and the presumably Paul Jal's Bude, but I don't have access to the latter at the moment):

> M. Brutus, qui cisalpinam Galliam optinebat, a Cn. Pompeio occisus est.

When it's not used as a proper name, though, it seems to be uniformly uncapitalized, like with *pergraecari*. These all were taken from PHI:

> Titus Maccius Plautus, Bacchides 813
>   Nic. Propterea hoc facio, ut suadeas gnato meo
>   ut pergraecetur tecum, tervenefice.
>   Chrys. O stulte, stulte, nescis nunc venire te;
>
> Titus Maccius Plautus, Mostellaria 22, 64
>   corrumpe erilem ádulescentem óptumum;
>   dies noctesque bibite, pergraecamini,
>   amicas emite liberate, pascite
>   date, si non estis. agite, porro pergite
>   quoniam occepistis: bibite, pergraecamini,
>   este, ecfercite vos, saginam caedite.
>
> Titus Maccius Plautus, Poenulus 603
>   liberum ut commostraremus tibi locum et voluptarium,
>   ubi ames, potes, pergraecere. Coll. Eu, edepol mortales malos.
>   Agor. Ego enim docui. Mil. Quis te porro? Coll. Agite intro abite, Agorastocles,
>
> Marcus Cornelius Fronto, fragmenta 12.1
>   parentum tuorum.
>   Et pergraecari potius amoenis locis quam coerceri carcere
>   viderentur.

*Pergraecari* is a verb meaning "to live like a Greek" (i.e. playfully, so "to revel"), whose root is *Graecus*, a proper adjective.

Based on this, I'd say put it in lower-case unless used as a substantive.

Comment: I'm not sure that ethnic adjectives like _Graecus_ and _Romanus_ must necessarily be capitalised; certainly they need not be in Neolatin languages like Spanish ([example](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribus_griegas)). Of course, mixed case is a late Mediaeval invention, so it is hard to say there is even a proper capitalisation strategy in Latin.

Comment: @Wtrmute French too doesn't capitalize those adjectives. Buy all that is why I pointed out that it comes down to editorial strategies. I don't think the original question meant to imply this was ancient.